# How to get number of affected rows from JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using spring `JdbcTemplate` to execute a sql query:

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
template.execute(sqlInsert); //returns void
```

How could I get the number of effected rows, as the `execute()` method returns void?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Call the [update](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update(org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator)) method of `JdbcTemplate`. It will gives you the number of effected rows as return value.

> **update**
>
> ```
> public int update(PreparedStatementCreator psc)
>        throws DataAccessException
> ```
>
> Description copied from interface: `JdbcOperations`
>
> Issue a single SQL update operation (such as
>   an insert, update or delete statement) using a
>   `PreparedStatementCreator` to provide SQL and any required parameters. 
>   A `PreparedStatementCreator` can either be implemented directly or
>   configured through a `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory`.
>
> **Specified by:**
>   update in interface `JdbcOperations`
>
> **Parameters:**
>   psc - object that provides SQL and any necessary parameters
>
> **Returns:**
>   the number of rows affected
>
> **Throws:**
>   `DataAccessException` - if there is any problem issuing the update
>
> **See Also:**
>   PreparedStatementCreatorFactory

Comment: Is this a good solution even if the sql is not an update statement (eg delete, truncate, whatever)?

Comment: @membersound Yes it is as  the documentation says "SQL update operation (such as an insert, update or delete statement) ".

Comment: @Jens that down voter is misguided. +1 to counter that.

Answer (score 8):

You can probably use `JdbcTemplate.update()` for that case. this will return the number of rows updated or deleted.

Comment: yes you can use for any type of statement (insert/update/delete and so on)